# Vue.js build a view from an object using separate array

Tags: javascript, vue.js

1. Change the html `select` and it updates the variable called `selected`.
2. Use the `selected` variable to retrieve the `array` with the same from the `hangOut` object.
3. Change the list to include just the two names (in that order) contained in that array.

So if `selected` is "often" than the list would show brown eyed jerry and green eyed jane. Here is the code and fiddle:

**HTML**

```
<div id="app">
  <select v-model="selected">
    <option v-for="(frequency,key) in selectOptions" :value="key">{{frequency}}</option>
  </select>
  <ul>
    <li v-for="(person,key) in persons" :key="key">
      {{ person.eyes + " eyed " + key }}
    </li>
    <p>These two like to hangout {{selected}}.</p>
  </ul>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
var vm = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    selected: "sometimes",
    selectOptions: {
      sometimes: "Sometimes",
      often: "Often",
      rarely: "Rarely"
    },
    persons: {
      joe: {
        height: 'Tall',
        eyes: 'blue',
        age: 30
      },
      jane: {
        height: 'Medium',
        eyes: 'green',
        age: 22
      },
      jerry: {
        height: 'short',
        eyes: 'brown',
        age: 33
      }
    },
    hangOut: {
      sometimes: ["joe", "jane"],
      often: ["jerry", "jane"],
      rarely: ["jerry", "joe"]
    }
  },
  computed: {
    filter() {
      var result = {}; //create new emptly object to return
      arr = this.hangOut["activeSelect"];
      for (var i = 0, len = arr.length; i < len; i++) {
        result[i]=arr[i];
      }
      return result;
    }
  }
})
```

**Fiddle**

https://jsfiddle.net/ty3ypmn0/5/

Comment: I don't understand what you want

Comment: Are you trying to print hangOut based on what you have selected?

Comment: If the select sets the variable called `selected` to `often` I want to get the two array items from the `often` array and use them as keys to return a new object from the `persons` object that contains just those two people in that order. This way the list updates. I am trying to use a computed function called `filter` that I made up but I don't think I am understanding it correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass the `this.selected` like `this.hangOut[this.selected]`  as the following code

```
computed: {
    filter() {
      var result = {}; //create new emptly object to return
      var arr = this.hangOut[this.selected];
      for (var i = 0, len = arr.length; i < len; i++) {
        result[i]=arr[i];
      }
      return result;
    }
  }
```

Follow the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/ty3ypmn0/9/

You have to access the computed property in your template `{{filter}}` and in js you can call like `this.filter`

Comment: How can I use the `filter` object in the html to get the result I want. Trying on my side and it feels close. I am just a little too new to vue.js I suppose.

Comment: Looks like that just returns `person` but when I try to use `person.eyes` it's undefined. Any ideas?

Comment: I gave a sample , `person.eyes` wont be available because , we didn't wrote a logic get the data in the new array

Answer (score 0):

Let's take a look at [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ty3ypmn0/6/):

I've refactored your code and made a computed method to handle selection:

```
listObjects() {
  let keys = Object.keys(this.persons).filter(key => this.hangOut[this.selected].indexOf(key) >= 0);

  let finalPeople = {};
  for(let i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
    let key = keys[i];
    finalPeople[key] = this.persons[key];
  }
  return finalPeople;
},
```

Let's see what the code is saying:

```
let keys = Object.keys(this.persons).filter(key => this.hangOut[this.selected].indexOf(key) >= 0);
```

This line finds the objects which you provided inside an array inside hangOut, I've used Object.keys to retrieve keys of persons (which should be people :D) then I've filtered ([Array.prototype.filter MDN reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)) them to retrieve only selected objects (take a look at this.hangOut[this.selected].indexOf(key)...)

and finally added the items to the returned object and rendered them.

Comment: How can I get it to hold the order of the items in the array?

Comment: Yes, it's possible but not with Object.keys there is an alternative for Object which was introduced in ECMA6 named Map, take a look at its official documentation at [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map)

Answer (score 0):

I add two others `<p>` to ilustrate what `selectedInfos` is returning.

First of all, when you are using the property `computed` in Vue think of variables that will change automatically if another variable inside your scope has changed (e.g when this.selected changes, selectedInfos will return something new and will updates).

I changed the `"activeSelected"` to `this.selected` to correctly keep tracking what you selected.

```js
var vm = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    selected: "sometimes",
    selectOptions: {
      sometimes: "Sometimes",
      often: "Often",
      rarely: "Rarely"
    },
    persons: {
      joe: {
        height: 'Tall',
        eyes: 'blue',
        age: 30
      },
      jane: {
        height: 'Medium',
        eyes: 'green',
        age: 22
      },
      jerry: {
        height: 'short',
        eyes: 'brown',
        age: 33
      }
    },
    hangOut: {
      sometimes: ["joe", "jane"],
      often: ["jerry", "jane"],
      rarely: ["jerry", "joe"]
    }
  },
  computed: {
    selectedInfos() {
      var result = []; //create new emptly object to return
      arr = this.hangOut[this.selected];
      for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        result.push(this.persons[arr[i]])
      }
      return result;
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.4.4/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <select v-model="selected">
    <option v-for="(frequency,key) in selectOptions" :value="key">{{frequency}}</option>
  </select>
  <ul>
    <li v-for="(person,key) in persons" :key="key">
      {{ person.eyes + " eyed " + key }}
    </li>
    <p>These two like to hangout: {{hangOut[selected][0]}} and {{hangOut[selected][1]}}
    </p>
    <p>Infos: {{selectedInfos}}
    </p>
    <p>OneInfo: {{selectedInfos[0]}}
    </p>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**[Like this ?](https://jsfiddle.net/ty3ypmn0/11/)**
You just need a computed filtered array, filteredPersons. You can see that its inputs are persons, hangOut and 'selected', so whenever one of those changes, filteredPersons will be recalculated.

**markup**

```
<div id="app">
  <select v-model="selected">
    <option v-for="(frequency,key) in selectOptions" :value="key">{{frequency}}</option>
  </select>
  <ul>
    <li v-for="(person,key) in persons">
      {{ person.eyes + " eyed " + person.name }}
    </li>
    <p>These two like to hangout {{selected}}.</p>
    {{filteredPersons}}
  </ul>
</div>
```

**js**

```
var vm = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    selected: "sometimes",
    selectOptions: {
      sometimes: "Sometimes",
      often: "Often",
      rarely: "Rarely"
    },
    persons: [
       {name: 'joe',
        height: 'Tall',
        eyes: 'blue',
        age: 30
      },
       {name: 'jane',
        height: 'Medium',
        eyes: 'green',
        age: 22
      },
       {name: 'jerry',
        height: 'short',
        eyes: 'brown',
        age: 33
      }
    ],
    hangOut: {
      sometimes: ["joe", "jane"],
      often: ["jerry", "jane"],
      rarely: ["jerry", "joe"]
    }
  },
  computed: {
    filteredPersons(){
      return this.persons.filter( pers => this.hangOut[this.selected].indexOf(pers.name) + 1);
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: How do I alter the list items with that data? That is where I am stuck

Comment: filteredPersons is computed property. You can see that its inputs are persons, hangOut and 'selected', so whenever one of those changes, filteredPersons will be recalculated. That's what you want, no?